# How to create nested grid in kendo?

Tags: kendo-grid

I am trying to create a nested grid that will fetch data and populate into 2 grid, parent and a child.

1. Child  grid has only 1 parent
2. Child  grid limited to adding 16 rows
3. Removing the parent row will re-fetch data from server
4. Child grid is always open

It similar to this http://dojo.telerik.com/UqURE

But finally should look like this https://photos.app.goo.gl/X6fcZ79779bgjrRZ8

Answer (score 1):

You need to have two kendo grid in your view and two javaScript Method to gets your additional data az method parameters :

The parent grid and its child should be something like this :

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ProjectName.Models.ViewModel.TasksStaticViewModel>()
          .Name("grid")
          .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
              .Ajax()
              .Read(read => read.Action("ReadActionName", "ControllerName").Data("additionalData"))
          )
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(c => c.Column1).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;" }).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center;" }).Width(130);
              columns.Bound(c => c.Column2).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;" }).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center;" }).Width(135);                  
          })

          .ToolBar(tool => tool.Template(
              @"<a id='lnkexportExcel' class='k-button k-button-icontext ' href='/Report/Tasks'><span></span>ExportToExcel</a>))
          .Pageable()
          .AutoBind(false)
          .Sortable()
          .Scrollable(s => s.Enabled(true))
          .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")               
    )
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <script id="template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ProjectName.Models.ViewModel.MyViewModel>()
          .Name("grid_#=Id#")
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(c => c.SubColumn1).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;" }).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center;" }).Width(100);
              columns.Bound(c => c.SubColumn2).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;" }).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center;" }).Width(100);
          })
          .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
              .Ajax()
              .Read(read => read.Action("ReadActionName", "ControllerName",
                      new { AgentSelectedId = "#=AgentId#", TaskHeaderSelectedId = "#=TaskHeaderId#"})
                      .Data("additionalData2"))
          ) 
          .Pageable()
          .Sortable()
          .ToClientTemplate()
        )
    </script>
</div>
```

And the two additional data which js javascript code :

```
function additionalData() {
        return someModel;}

function additionalData2() {
     return someModel;}
```

If it was useful, check it as an answer, please